# Cannot find an initializer for type UIImage that accepts an argument list of type string

Tags: ios, swift, initializer-list

Currently, this code is working , but paris is a fixed value, i would like to input a variable, and define it just before.

```
let entry1 = data.paris[indexPath.row]
let  image = UIImage(named: entry1.filename)
cell2.bkImageView2.image = image
cell2.headingLabel2.text = entry1.heading
```

But when i do it like this just below an error appears. Cannot find an initializer for type UIImage that accepts an argument list of type (named:string?!)

```
let key1 = "paris"
let entry1 = data[key1][indexPath.row]
let  image = UIImage(named: entry1.filename)
cell2.bkImageView2.image = image
cell2.headingLabel2.text = entry1.heading
```

Have you any information to help me ?

Edit : 29 July 13h12

Ok, Following your explains, i have this :

```
var entry = data[key][indexPath.row]
if let imgName = entry1.filename {
            let  image = UIImage(named: imgName!)
            cell2.bkImageView2.image = image
            cell2.headingLabel2.text = entry1.heading
        }
```

But now, i have still a error on last sentence (cell2.headinglabel...) : Ambiguous use of "heading"

Any idea ? But for the previous request, perfect ! Great job ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that `entry1.filename` is optional string, not string, try this:

```
if let imgName = entry1.filename {
    let  image = UIImage(named: imgName)
}
```

Just remember that image is optional as well.

Comment: It should be the same when i used a fixed value ( as paris just above) , no ? I don't understand why,  when i used a variable , this problem occurs.

Comment: in your example paris is a String but data dictionary returns an optional value (because it's possible that there is no value for defined key) so your entry1 is optional, so thats why you have to unwrap it.

Comment: @HugoCELLA try that: cell2.headingLabel2.text = entry1!.heading

Comment: i will do it. Why i have to do that ? have you any link to learn about that ? thx

Comment: i will have access to my computer, in 4 hours. I let u know thx

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84598/discussion-between-hugo-cella-and-greg).

Comment: didn't work, Xcode wants that i delete the "!" and following message appears : operand of postfix "!" should have optional type, type is AnyObject

Comment: and even with the first change, there s not any error anymore, but image doesn't appear !

Comment: @HugoCELLA As I said in my answer the image is an optional so you have to unwrap it to see the image, like: UIImage(named: imgName)!